# How to generate a sequence of numbers and print them in a row separated by comma

Tags: shell

I need to generate a sequence of numbers and print them in a row split by comma. For example:
1,2,3,4,5

I used "seq n" to generate the sequence in a file and use vim to replace returns with comma.

I find this is a bit awkward. Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

`seq -s "," 5` should be all you need. `-s` = separator character.

e.g.

```
marc$ seq -s "," 5
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I want! But the problem is there would be a comma at the end. Any ideas of removing it?

Comment: with this? there's no comma at the end. what I pasted above as the sample is actual cut/paste of the command+output.

Comment: Thanks Marc. I copy and paste your command in my terminal and there is a comma at the end. Do you use Mac btw? I just use one more sed command to replace the comma.

Comment: newp. ubuntu 14.04. must be something about the bsd/mac version of sed. mine's gnu sed 4.2.2

Comment: @MarcB: sed --> seq :)

Answer (score 2):

GNU seq includes the separator argument, so you can do:

```
seq --separator=, 5
```

Comment: But there would be one comma at the end. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: @user3139647, there is no comma at the end.

Comment: Do you use Mac OSX? It shows a comma at the end in my terminal. I just use one more sed command to replace it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I like `{1..5}` operator!

```
echo {1..4}, 5
```

Comment: This works. thanks. It seems there is a space after the comma. Do you know how to remove it?

Comment: @Mengwen, Sorry I cant remove this space directly ! Perhaps `perl -e 'print join(",",1..5)'`

Comment: Thanks JJoao. This helps! See others replies. using seq -s "," 5 is also great.